# Android Dialog box alternative in iPhone

Tags: ios

I would like to know if there is something in iPhone that resembles dialog box in Android? I have several views to display inside dialog boxes. Each view, I need to control from Dialog box for click events.

Comment: I strongly urge you to read the [iOS HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead of just making an Android app that happens to run on iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is a very good idea, but maybe you can try to create custom UIAlertViews. Or show modal viewcontrollers.